# Why do my armor plates only insert 1 even when I'm holding down the armor plates button?

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone

I'm using PC and at some point something changed in my setup so that when press and hold the bottom to insert my armor plates (F10 on my machine), it will insert just 1 plate. In the past, if I pressed and held the button, it will keep inserting plates until I was full, but at some point it stopped doing this.

What setting should I change to get this feature back?

Answer (score 1):

Spam 'insert armor' button and it will insert several in the same animation. I think i had same setting but was removed at some time.